# How do I list user defined types in a HANA SQL Database?

Tags: sql, hana

I would like to be able to obtain a list of user defined types, similar to listing user defined procedures by calling

```
select * from SYS.PROCEDURES order by PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

Comment: The table `DATA_TYPES` seems to contain only information about the default data types, but nothing about user defined types (i.e. definded with `CREATE TYPE`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As table types are the only user-definable types in SAP HANA you find those in the TABLES system table:

```
SELECT 
       * 
FROM 
     tables 
WHERE 
      is_user_defined_type ='TRUE';
```

cheers,
Lars